# empty directory after migrating SVN to Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration, git-svn

I am migrating a repository from SVN to Git.

I attempted this comand to clone SVN to Git but this created an empty Git repo with empty commit

```
git svn clone --prefix=origin/ --authors-file=users.txt --username=ankur -s -r31671:HEAD https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/
```

I also tried with different commands

```
git svn clone --username=ankur -s -r31671:HEAD https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/
```

and

```
git svn clone --authors-file=users.txt --username=ankur -s https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/
```

and

```
git svn clone --authors-file=users.txt --username=ankur https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/
```

and

```
git svn clone https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/
```

I tried lots of searching but failed

`svn.companydomain.com` is resolving perfectly (`192.168.xxx.xxx`)

output of : **svn ls https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/**

```
.classpath
.project
.settings/
Documents/
example/
pom.xml
src/
```

Comment: Do you do a one-time converson or do you want to use Git as frontend to an existing SVN repository that remains the canonical repository?

Comment: show output of `svn ls https://svn.companydomain.com/svn/folder/project/`

Comment: @LazyBadger please check question. I have update your question's answer.

Comment: @Vampire can you explain your question

Comment: @AnkurLoriya I don't know what you don't understand. I can repeat the question though. Do you want to do a one-time conversion and then everyone only uses Git from then on, or do you use Git as frontend to an SVN repostitory that remains the canonical repository and is used by others directly?

Comment: @Vampire I want one-time conversion after migration I will be stop using SVN but I want all SVN change commit must be in GIT repo

Answer (score 0):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

Comment: why is `git-svn` not good tool for the one-time conversions? Have done those many times without major issues. @Vampire could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MykolaGurov well, it is easier to start with, but it produces much worse results, the history is rebuilt better by `svn2git`, the tags are real tags and not branches, if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually, with 'svn2git'  you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily or combine multiple SVN repositories into one Git repository easily,  ... There are many reasons `git-svn` is worse, too much to list them in a comment.

Comment: If it is easy and it works then it is better. For when it works. There might be cases (maybe this one) where svn2git would be more preferable solution, but to say that git svn is not right tool for the one-time conversions of repositories without being more specific is wrong, IMHO.

Comment: I already gave you multiple reasons why and I won't discuss a given fact with you in comments of a question, sry. EOC

Comment: Yet another reason, with git-svn the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper `svn2git` tags are where they belong.